# Angular5 HTTP service with Indexeddb as an offline datastore: how to handle Observable<response> vs Object

Tags: angular, http, indexeddb, angular2-observables

I have an Angular 5 app storing data in a database, which I fetch via service calls like this:

```
this.dataSvc
    .getSomeData()
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => { this.someVariable = data }
    )
```

Where the services are basically this:

```
 public getSomeData(): Observable<Response> {
      return this.http.get(SERVER_URL);
 }
```

I have an indexeddb service running, and when the network is available, every time I fetch data from a service above, I save the returned data into the indexeddb store as an object, and when the network is not available, and the service is called, I want to fetch the object from the indexeddb store instead and return it instead of fetching via the network.

```
 if (this.networkStatus == 'Offline') {
      this.idbService.getRecord('idbStore')
      .subscribe(data => {
           console.log("Idb Data: ",data);
           return Observable.of(data);
      }
 } else {
      return this.http.get(SERVER_URL);
 }
```

The problem is that 'return Observable.of(data)' isn't correct, and on the component side the network return gets a response, and it can map the response to json etc., but the indexeddb call returns an object that can't be mapped to json as it's already a javascript object.

I want to handle the online/offline situation at the service level - I know that I could do this in the component, and call an online service when there's a network and use the Observable form, and call an offline service when there's no network and receive a javascript object, but some of these services are used in a lot of components, and I'd like to centralize the code that handles the online/offline condition rather than replicating that code in every component.

The question is how do I handle the return of the object fetched from the indexeddb store so as to have it formatted in a way the code expecting an HTTP response will handle it properly?

Or alternately, is there a different / better method for solving this problem that's hiding in my blindspot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't subscribe to the `getRecord()` call. Instead return that:

```js
return this.idbService.getRecord('idbStore');
```

Based on your comment, you will need this:

```js
if (this.networkStatus == 'Offline') 
{
    return this.idbService.getRecord('idbStore');
} else {
    return this.http.get(SERVER_URL)
        .map(response => response.json());
}
```

And change the other part to this:

```js
this.dataSvc
    .getSomeData()
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.someVariable = data;
    });
```

Comment: That throws an error 'TypeError: response.json is not a function'

Comment: You need to move `.map(response => response.json())` to the `else` portion of this code then

Comment: That works, it does require some code changes on all the components using the service, which I was hoping to avoid, but it's certainly manageable.